# Change stamp font?

Tags: rendering

Is there a way/a script to change the font of the stamp you can put on your renders (the thing that displays render times ect.) because I don't really like the default font.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way built into Blender to do this, the best you can do is change the font size.**

As for scripts, I don't see why it could not be done, but I would need a much better understanding of both Python and the Blender source code to give a definite answer, or write a script.

Comment: Just had a spelunk into the source and found that the code for generating the VSE Text effect and the Stamp are the same and all the references to the font are hard coded. The developer even marked the lines with // XXX which appears to be a flag for janky code. Look for "do_text_effect" in "source/blender/blenkernel/intern/seqeffects.c" Maybe it will be fixed in 2.8

Comment: Man that sucks, I hope they do change it for 2.8+